# Iso generation is supported for data classes with up to 22 constructor parameters

Tags: arrow-kt

@optics data class test( 1,2,...23) {
companion object
}

[ERROR]   Iso generation is supported for data classes with up to 22 constructor parameters.

Answer (score 3):

bodduluri,

In Arrow-kt we only support automatic generation for `Iso` up to `22 parameters`. The reason for this is that Arrow only has `Tuple3` -> `Tuple22` defined. `Pair` and `Triple` from Kotlin Std are also used.

The example you shared `data class test( 1,2,...23)` has 23 parameters, so Arrow cannot generate the desired `Iso`.

You can still automatically genrate `Lens` and `Optional` for your `data class` by specifying `@optics(arrow.optics.OpticsTarget.Lens, arrow.optics.OpticsTarget.Optional)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and the detailed explanation